# What is that - Interrupted system call (max_fd=38)?

Tags: php, cron, system-calls

I have a several timed wget processes in cron (PHP scripts) and now I'm getting this warning sometimes around 5-8am. Scripts search and fetch data via API. When this warning is logged, it takes hour or maybe two before script continues to search data. Like it's stuck...

```
Warning: stream_select(): unable to select [4]: Interrupted system call (max_fd=38) in processmanager.php on line 189
```

And what I have on line 189

```
$write = $except = NULL;
stream_select($streams, $write, $except, 0, 300000);
```